# Error: PostgreSQL type 'regclass' isn't supported by Npgsql

Tags: c#, postgresql, npgsql, timescaledb

I got this error when I'm trying to decompress chunks in **TimescaleDB** from .NET C# app. When I do the same in pgAdmin - everything goes fine.

What is wrong?

**Code**

```cs
public static void DecompressChunks()
{
    string query = "SELECT decompress_chunk(chunk, if_compressed => true) " +
                   "FROM show_chunks(relation => 'sensorsdata', " +
                                    "newer_than => '2021-09-13 15:15:29.305'::timestamp, " +
                                    "older_than => '2021-09-27 15:15:29.305'::timestamp) " +
                   "AS chunk;";

    using var connection = new NpgsqlConnection(_timescaleConnectionString);
    connection.Query(query);
}
```

**Stack**

```
System.NotSupportedException: PostgreSQL type 'regclass' isn't supported by Npgsql
   at Npgsql.TypeMapping.ConnectorTypeMapper.ResolveByDataTypeName(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError)
   at Npgsql.TypeMapping.ConnectorTypeMapper.TryResolveByOID(UInt32 oid, NpgsqlTypeHandler& handler)
   at Npgsql.TypeMapping.ConnectorTypeMapper.ResolveByOID(UInt32 oid)
   at Npgsql.BackendMessages.FieldDescription.ResolveHandler()
   at Npgsql.BackendMessages.RowDescriptionMessage.Load(NpgsqlReadBuffer buf, ConnectorTypeMapper typeMapper)
   at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.ParseServerMessage(NpgsqlReadBuffer buf, BackendMessageCode code, Int32 len, Boolean isPrependedMessage)
   at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.ReadMessage(Boolean async, DataRowLoadingMode dataRowLoadingMode, Boolean readingNotifications)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.NextResult(Boolean async, Boolean isConsuming, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.NextResult()
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at Dapper.SqlMapper.ExecuteReaderWithFlagsFallback(IDbCommand cmd, Boolean wasClosed, CommandBehavior behavior) in /_/Dapper/SqlMapper.cs:line 1066
   at Dapper.SqlMapper.QueryImpl[T](IDbConnection cnn, CommandDefinition command, Type effectiveType)+MoveNext() in /_/Dapper/SqlMapper.cs:line 1094
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Dapper.SqlMapper.Query[T](IDbConnection cnn, String sql, Object param, IDbTransaction transaction, Boolean buffered, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, Nullable`1 commandType) in /_/Dapper/SqlMapper.cs:line 734
   at Dapper.SqlMapper.Query(IDbConnection cnn, String sql, Object param, IDbTransaction transaction, Boolean buffered, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, Nullable`1 commandType) in /_/Dapper/SqlMapper.cs:line 661
   at DapperTimescaleCaller.EntryPoint.Program.DecompressChunks() in C:\Users\Arthur\source\repos\DapperTimescaleCaller\DapperTimescaleCaller.EntryPoint\Program.cs:line 35
   at DapperTimescaleCaller.EntryPoint.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\Arthur\source\repos\DapperTimescaleCaller\DapperTimescaleCaller.EntryPoint\Program.cs:line 14
```

**PgAdmin**

[image]

Comment: You may need to cast it to `varchar` as `Npgsql` doesn't support it. `show_chunks(....)::varchar`

Comment: @Eldar yes, you're right! I put **::varchar** to **decompress_chunk** function and now it works. I don't know how to highlight your answer, sir :(

Comment: Glad to help. No further action needed.